# Gridview onrowcommand on firing

Tags: asp.net, gridview, rowcommand

This is my grid view

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"
          OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
          OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating"
          OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btn1" Text="edit" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id") %>' CommandName="Edit" ></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="Button1" Text="delete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id") %>' CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick=' return confirm("do you want to delete")' ></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is the function call

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        //Response.Write(e.CommandArgument);
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();

        string query = "delete from brand where id='" + e.CommandArgument + "'";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query,conn);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        fillgrid();
    }
}
```

The `onrowcommand` does not get fired. Why?

Comment: Did you dubug with Breakpoint.? Still its not firing?

Comment: I suppose you are binding your grid in page_load simply. Dont bind the grid on postback, bind with in "if(!IsPostback)".

Comment: i did that already still not working

Comment: Enable viewstate to true.You must not bind your grid on postbacks in Page_Load, only when something changed that causes the Grid to reload data(f.e. Sorting,Paging) and only in the appropriate even-handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing: because your `Page_Load` looks similar to this:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBindGridView(); // here you load the datasource of the grid and call DataBind();
}
```

Do not `DataBind` the grid on postbacks, otherwise events aren't triggered since you overwrite changes with the values form database, so this should work then:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
        DataBindGridView(); // here you load the datasource of the grid and call DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable viewstate:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="something.cs"
    ValidateRequest="false" Inherits="something" EnableViewState="true" %>
```

In the `Page load` event, do:

```
if(!IsPostback)
{
    callmethodtobindgrid();
}
```

Rowcommand event handler:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        //Response.Write(e.CommandArgument);
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();

        string query = "delete from brand where id='" + e.CommandArgument + "'";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        fillgrid();
    }
}
```